# Android Test project setup in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

When I try to set up an "Android Test Project" in eclipse Juno, on the Select Test Target window, I don't see a browse button to choose AUT.

Anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After selecting ***File -> New -> Other... -> Android Test Project***, youl be prompted for the project name and then you can select a target project

[image]